# R create loop for comparing rows

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, compare

I got a dataframe like this:

```
  id      day  time state 
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
1 A         1     1     0     
2 A         1     2     0     
3 A         1     3     1     
4 A         2     1     0     
5 A         2     2     1     
6 A         2     3     1     
7 A         3     1     1     
8 A         3     2     1     
9 A         3     3     0
```

In the original dataframe, there are 30 ids and every id has 5 days with 1440 timepoints (so 216000 rows in total).

Now I want to create a new variable called "delta" as result for comparing if the state (1 or 0) is equal between two different timeponts (1 = equal, 0 = unequal).

For example:
Compare if state of day 1 time 1 is = state of day 2 time 1, day 1 time 2 = day 2 time 2....
and then day 2 time 1 = day 3 time 1 and so on.
In the end it should look like this:

```
 id      day  time state delta
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     1     0     1
2 A         1     2     0     0
3 A         1     3     1     1
4 A         2     1     0     0
5 A         2     2     1     1
6 A         2     3     1     0
7 A         3     1     1     1
8 A         3     2     1     0
9 A         3     3     0     1
```

I already tried some codes with the ifelse-command, but I could work it out yet.

Comment: So the `day i` `time j` row, the `delta` value compares if `day i + 1` `time j` (next day, same time) is equal. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my assumption here is correct: you want for the `day i` `time j` row, the `delta` value compares if the `state` on `day i + 1` `time j` (next day, same time) is equal.

Here's a `dplyr` method:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>% 
  group_by(time) %>%
  arrange(day) %>%
  mutate(delta = as.integer(lead(state) == state))
```